# Database Sorting by Count

Tags: php, database, sorting, laravel-5

i have 2 table

**File**

```
File_ID
File_Name
OtherAttribute
```

**Like**

```
Like_ID
File_ID
User_ID
```

how can i sort the file by counting the like of the file itself?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by counts of like try query below. Which will get count first then sort accordingly

```
Select f.* from FILE f 
ORDER BY (SELECT count(Like_ID) as like_cnt FROM `Like` as `l` 
WHERE l.File_ID = f.File_ID GROUP BY l.File_ID) DESC;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/091f3/16)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    f.File_Name, COUNT(l.Like_ID) as FILE_LIKE 
FROM 
    File f 
LEFT JOIN Like l ON l.File_ID = f.File_ID 
GROUP BY f.File_ID 
ORDER BY FILE_LIKE
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select * 

from FILE F 

ORDER BY (SELECT count(Like_ID) as like_cnt FROM 'Like' as 'l' 

WHERE l.File_ID = F.File_ID GROUP BY l.File_ID) Asec;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Code is always more helpful when accompanied by an explanation. This is especially true when answering an old question with existing answers. How does this improve upon what's already here?